# How to select, match and return values in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, transfers and clubs.

This is the table transfers:

| id | firstname | lastname | fromclub | toclub | forprice | frombacknumber | tobacknumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Example1 | Example2 | EX3 | EX4 | Example5 | Example6 | Example7 |

This is the table clubs:

| id | abbr | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | EX3 | Example3 |
| 1 | EX4 | Example4 |

I want to take a row from the table transfers, get the fromclub, match it with the abbr in clubs, get the fullname from that row, and add it to the response. I want to do the same thing for the toclub column. Then I want to repeat it for every other row in the table transfers.

To simplify, here is my expected result:

| id | firstname | lastname | fromclub | toclub | forprice | frombacknumber | tobacknumber | fromclubfullname | toclubfullname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Example1 | Example2 | EX3 | EX4 | Example5 | Example6 | Example7 | Example3 | Example4 |

I cannot seem to find a way to build a query that does this without getting about 512 rows of results even though I only have 8 at the moment.

```
SELECT *
FROM transfers,
(SELECT clubs.fullname FROM transfers, clubs WHERE clubs.abbr = transfers.fromclub) AS fromclubfullname,
(SELECT clubs.fullname FROM transfers, clubs WHERE clubs.abbr = transfers.toclub) AS toclubfullname
```

It returns 512 rows and two columns called fullname, instead of a column fromclubfullname and toclubfullname.

Comment: Can you share what your current query looks like?

Comment: It looks like a fairly straightforward join, with the only peculiarity that you'll need the clubs table twice. If you're getting 512 rows, you must have messed the join conditions. Please update the question and share your current code.

Comment: you can use join or subquery to solve your issue, Where you stuck?

Comment: This was my last kind of working query: ```SELECT * FROM transfers, (SELECT clubs.fullname FROM transfers, clubs WHERE clubs.abbr = transfers.fromclub) AS fromclubfullname, (SELECT clubs.fullname FROM transfers, clubs WHERE clubs.abbr = transfers.toclub) AS toclubfullname```, but it returns 512 rows and two columns called fullname, instead of a column fromclubfullname and toclubfullname.

Comment: Columns to display go into the `SELECT` clause. You're doing nested Cartesian products instead.

Comment: On a side note, the `FROM a, b` way to join tables was already old 2 decades ago. You may want to check more up-to-date learning resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `left join` -

```
SELECT 
     transfers.*,
     c1.fullname as fromclubfullname,
     c2.fullname as toclubfullname FROM `transfers`
LEFT JOIN clubs c1 ON (c1.abbr = transfers.fromclub)
LEFT JOIN clubs c2 ON (c2.abbr = transfers.toclub)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `ON` is not a function so parenthesis do not really do anything (they don't break things, either).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, you are right.But it's just way making code somewhat clear to see.